# Coloured background given different equation lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that looks as follow:

```
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(x=runif(100)*10,y=runif(100)*10)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y) ) + geom_point() + theme_classic2()+
geom_abline(intercept = 4, slope = 2, color="gray",linetype="dotted")+
geom_abline(intercept = -3, slope = 2, color="gray",linetype="dotted")
```

I wish to grade the areas over/between/under the dotted line according to what shown in the plot below. What things can I try?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to just work out the coordinates of the individual polygons and place them under your points:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(survminer)
#> Warning: package 'survminer' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
#> Loading required package: magrittr

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100) * 10, y = runif(100) * 10)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 20, 20), y = c(4, 44, 64, 44)),
               fill = "green") + 
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 20, 20), y = c(-3, 4, 44, 37)),
               fill = "yellow") + 
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 20, 20), y = c(-20, -3, 37, -20)),
               fill = "orange") + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic2() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 4, slope = 2, color = "gray", linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_abline(intercept = -3, slope = 2, color = "gray", linetype = "dotted") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Allan! It works perfectly. Though, I hoped for a bit more fix solution. If nothing else shows up until the day after tomorrow, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks @A.joh. If you want to use data (including formulas) to draw shapes and colours in ggplot, you need to use a geom. The other options you have here would be geom_ribbon and geom_area. It would certainly be possible to create an easy-to-use solution by wrapping this up in a function or creating a new geom. However, this probably isn't worth doing unless you are going to create a lot of plots like this.

Comment: U are right. That is exactly what I want to do. I'll go with this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to handle non-linear functions?

Comment: @A.joh you would use geom_area or geom_ribbon for these. If you want to post a new question with an example of what you're looking for I'd be happy to take a look at a more general solution

Comment: Thank you! I think I sought out following your guidelines!